# Get Value Spinner in Android

Tags: android, get, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I want to get value from spinner with item like this.

> 11 Ina | 12 Ani | 13 Nia

I used two string for 11 and Ina.
This is example for show my spinner: `spinner.add(stringone+stringtwo)`

Can I get value when click **Ina**, only **11**?

Comment: Does Spinner class have an **add();** method??

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming that your input works fine, you can use the split method to take only the input that you need.

```
 `String selectedItem =` `mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().subString(beginIndex,endIndex);`
```

Note that `beginIndex` is inclusive and `endIndex` is exclusive. In your case, subString(0,2) will return you 11 alone.

You can also go for `split()` method if you want to further customise breakdown of the selected item. Refer [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/string/java-string-split-example/) for more details.

Comment: if i used "stringone" that value 11,12,13. Can i get the value used "stringone" to selectedItem in spinner?

Comment: if what you try to achieve is to get only the integers form the selectedItem, you can go for something like, `String numbersAlone = str.replaceAll("[^0-9|]","");
String[] numbers = numbersAlone.split("|");` This will give an array of only the integers from selectedItem